# How can I move the window by clicking the my custom title in QDialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qdialog

When I press title bar or frame_title I want to move the window
but I don't know how I can do it.This QDialog window pops up when I press a button.However, I cannot move the QDialog window.I want to move the window with drag and drop with the mouse.I shared the my code free of unnecessary things.so things may seem incomplete and absurd.

```
def Musteri_Ekle_Penceresi(self):
    mustekledialog=QDialog()
    mustekledialog.setGeometry(600, 280, 880, 651)

    mustekledialog.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    mustekledialog.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

    self.drop_shadow_layout = QVBoxLayout(mustekledialog)

    self.drop_shadow_frame = QFrame(mustekledialog)
    self.drop_shadow_frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
    self.drop_shadow_frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

    self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.drop_shadow_frame)

    self.title_bar = QFrame(self.drop_shadow_frame)
    self.title_bar.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
    self.title_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
    
    self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.title_bar)

    self.frame_title = QFrame(self.title_bar)
    self.frame_title.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
    self.frame_title.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
    self.verticalLayout_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.frame_title)
    self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
    self.label_title = QLabel(self.frame_title)
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_title)
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_title)
    self.frame_btns = QFrame(self.title_bar)
    self.frame_btns.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
    self.frame_btns.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
    self.horizontalLayout_3 = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_btns)
    self.btn_minimize = QPushButton(self.frame_btns)             
    self.btn_minimize.clicked.connect(mustekledialog.showMinimized)
    self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_minimize)
    self.btn_maximize = QPushButton(self.frame_btns)
    self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_maximize)
    self.btn_close = QPushButton(self.frame_btns)
    self.btn_close.clicked.connect(mustekledialog.close)

    self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_close)
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_btns)
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.title_bar)
    self.content_bar = QFrame(self.drop_shadow_frame)

    self.content_bar.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
    self.content_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
    self.verticalLayout_4 = QVBoxLayout(self.content_bar)
    self.frame = QFrame(self.content_bar)
    self.frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
    self.frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
    self.mEkle_ad = QLineEdit(self.frame)
    self.mEkle_soyad = QLineEdit(self.frame)
    self.mEkle_tel = QLineEdit(self.frame)
    self.mEkle_mail = QLineEdit(self.frame)
    self.mEkle_TC = QLineEdit(self.frame)
    self.label = QLabel(self.frame)
    self.label_2 = QLabel(self.frame)
    self.label_3 = QLabel(self.frame)
    self.label_4 = QLabel(self.frame)
    self.label_5 = QLabel(self.frame)
    self.mEkle_adres = QPlainTextEdit(self.frame)
    self.mEkle_kaydet = QPushButton(self.frame)

    self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.frame)
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.content_bar)
    self.credits_bar = QFrame(self.drop_shadow_frame)
    self.credits_bar.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
    self.credits_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
    self.horizontalLayout_2 = QHBoxLayout(self.credits_bar)
    self.frame_label_credits = QFrame(self.credits_bar)
    self.frame_label_credits.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
    self.frame_label_credits.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
    self.verticalLayout_3 = QVBoxLayout(self.frame_label_credits)
    self.label_credits = QLabel(self.frame_label_credits)
    self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_credits)
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_label_credits)
    self.frame_grip = QFrame(self.credits_bar)
    self.frame_grip.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
    self.frame_grip.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_grip)
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.credits_bar)
    self.drop_shadow_layout.addWidget(self.drop_shadow_frame)


    mustekledialog.show()
    mustekledialog.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple implementation uses a subclass of QFrame (which is what you're using as a "title bar") and implement the mouse events in order to move its top level window.

The concept is to get the position of the mouse press event (local to the frame), compute the difference in the mouse move event, and set the new position by adding the current window position and the above difference.

```
class DragWidget(QFrame):
    startPos = None
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.startPos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton and self.startPos is not None:
            delta = event.pos() - self.startPos
            self.window().move(self.window().pos() + delta)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.startPos = None


class YourWindow(QMainWindow):
    def Musteri_Ekle_Penceresi(self):
        # ...
        self.title_bar = DragWidget(self.drop_shadow_frame)
        # ...
```